# Existence of bases under conditions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces, with $T:V \rightarrow W$ a linear transformation. Prove that bases {$\overrightarrow v_{1},...,\overrightarrow v_{n}$} for V and {$\overrightarrow w_{1},...,\overrightarrow w_{m}$} for W exist such that

$T(\overrightarrow v_{i})=$
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\overrightarrow w_{i}, 1\le i\le k \\
\overrightarrow 0, k<i\le n
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

where $k$ is some integer, $0\le k\le n$. (If $k=0$, then $T(\overrightarrow v_{i})=\overrightarrow 0$ for $1\le i \le n$.)

My approach:

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional with {$\overrightarrow v_{1},..,\overrightarrow v_{n}$} basis for $V$ and {$\overrightarrow w_{1},...,\overrightarrow w_{m}$} basis for $W$.

By the linear extension theorem, $\exists$ unique linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow W$ such that $T(\overrightarrow v_{i})=\overrightarrow w_{i}$ $1\le i\le n$

We define T, for $1\le k\le n$ as: $T(\overrightarrow v_{1})=\overrightarrow w_{1}$ ... $T(\overrightarrow v_{k})=\overrightarrow w_{k}$, $T(\overrightarrow v_{k+1})=\overrightarrow 0$ ... $T(\overrightarrow v_{n})=\overrightarrow 0$

And if $k=0$, $T(\overrightarrow v_{i})=\overrightarrow 0$ for $1\le i\le n$

$\therefore$ We conclude that such bases exist, but only with the condition $k\le m$.

Is my approach correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: The problem is that you're doing this backwards : you should define two basis with the required property with given $T$, but here you construct $T$ *after* choosing the basis.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I decided to do it backwards because I have no theorem that guarantees the existence of bases, the linear extension theorem only guarantees existence of linear transformation. How should I go about it?

Comment: m>=n? If not, k must be <= min {n,m}

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this would be to take a basis $w_1,\dots,w_k$ of the subspace $T(V)$ of $W$, then complete it to get a basis of $W$. Then you take elements in $V$ mapping to the basis of $T(V)$ (so that $T(v_i)=w_i$ for $1\leq i\leq k$), show that they are linearly independant in $V$, and complete this to get a basis of $V$. Then it remains to prove that $T(v_i)=0$ for $i>k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't start from given bases of $V$ and $W$ and hope they will be the ones you're looking for. The map $T$ is given at the outset and you can't change it (which is what you're doing in your attempt).

Instead you should start from a basis $\{w_1,\dots,w_k\}$ of the image of $T$ and extend it to a basis $\{w_1,\dots,w_k,\dots,w_m\}$ of $W$.

For $i=1,\dots,k$, choose $v_i\in V$ such that $T(v_i)=w_i$ (they exist because $w_1,\dots,w_k$ belong to the image of $T$). Then $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ is linearly independent.

Choose a basis $\{u_1,\dots,u_h\}$ of $\ker T$ and prove that
$$
\{v_1,\dots,v_k,u_1,\dots,u_h\}
$$
is a basis of $V$, so $h=\dim V-k$ and you can set
$$
v_{k+1}=u_1,\dots, v_n=u_h
$$
to get the basis you want.